# How to access a docker container from another LAN pc within a home network

Tags: tomcat, docker, networking

I am new in docker world and I am using docker with virtual box with Oracle VM in windows 10 environment (laptop).I can access a container (example tomcat ) from by host pc. **But I want to access the container from another desktop pc within the same LAN.**

For this , I have created a bridge network with Ethernet and Virtual Host only Ethernet Adapter #3 and used this new bridge as Adapter 3 in my Virtual Machine XYZ. I have tried to run the image as

`docker run --name testomcat -d -p 192.168.0.100:8087:80 tomcat:latest`.

But with no luck. Container failed to start.

Got driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint error.

Am I in right track ? Can any body help, please?

Comment: can you ping the ip address of the container? would it be sufficient to access the tomcat via the host ip ?

Comment: Yes I want to access the tomcat via host ip, even I would like to access mysql with 3360 from another desktop pc . I can access it via localhost:8087  but not 192.168.0.100:8087

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible to do. There are different configurations that you can use for this.

**NAT + Bridged Adapter**

In this config you will have a NAT Adapter 1 and a Bridged Adapter 2. The bridged adapter will use same Source that your other PC is on. So if other PC uses wifi then keep this also on Wifi.

This will give your VM a IP directly from WIFI. Let' assume this IP to be `192.168.0.101`, your Host IP to `192.168.0.100` and other PC on `192.168.0.102`

#### Adapter 1

[image: Adapter 1]

#### Adapter 2

[image: Adapter 2]

Now from your Host PC and other PC you can reach the app on `.101`. You run the container as

```
docker run --name testomcat -d -p 8087:80 tomcat:latest
```

**NAT + Port Forwarding**

In this case you will have a NAT adapter and enable port forwarding of 8087 to 8087. The docker run will remain same

```
docker run --name testomcat -d -p 8087:80 tomcat:latest
```

#### Port mapping

[image: Port Mapping]

The app will be reachable at `192.168.0.100:8087`

**Troubleshooting**

If it doesn't then few things you need to check

```
sudo iptables -S | grep -i reject
sudo iptables -S | grep -i drop
```

Above should not give you rules that reject traffic or drop traffic

```
sudo ufw status
```

Make sure the firewall is also disabled

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My docker hosted pc is connected with cable.And other device are connected through wi-fi. For option 1 (NAT+Bridge Adapter), can you please elaborate with few steps? Thanks agian

Comment: Added screenshot for better explanation, also if one is on Wifi and one on ethernet then make sure that router has Network isolation disabled. In isolation mode the router will not allow wifi devices to talk to lan devices